# Linking Vertex ID to coordinates in PyMeshLab

Tags: vertex, meshlab, pymeshlab

I am looking to be able able to link the Vertex ID with the coordinate positions.

Using `m.edge_matrix` I can generate the list of vertex IDs for the edges that form a polyline. What is the easiest way to link this back to the actual coordinates?

Using `m.vertex_matrix` produces the list of coordinates, but has no reference to the Vertex ID. The order in which the coordinates are listed in `m.vertex_matrix` doesn't appear to link to the order in which they appear in `m.edge_matrix`

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The matrix returned by `m.vertex_matrix()` is **indexable**. The row n corresponds to coordinates of vertex with id=n, so you just need to use [ ] to read the row.

```py
v = m.vertex_matrix()
for e in m.edge_matrix():
  print("edge", e, "goes from", v[e[0]], "to", v[e[1]])
```

which produces this output:

```
edge [0 1] goes from [0.12843863 0.38690682 0.1] to [0.13383933 0.3839188  0.1]
edge [2 3] goes from [0.14307424 0.38100217 0.1] to [0.13592989 0.38318165 0.1]
edge [3 1] goes from [0.13592989 0.38318165 0.1] to [0.13383933 0.3839188  0.1]
edge [4 5] goes from [0.25161905 0.21663008 0.1] to [0.2520413  0.21464215 0.1]
edge [6 5] goes from [0.25537567 0.20097797 0.1] to [0.2520413  0.21464215 0.1]
```